# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception in List while using get method in Android

Tags: android

```
String location = "Mumbai";
List<Address> addressl = null;
if(location != null || !location.equals("")) {
  Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
  try {
    addressl = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 1);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Address address= addressl.get(0);
```

The above code is giving me exception in the last line...please help

Comment: ^ that makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

`Geocoder.getFromLocationName()` returns

> a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

You need to be prepared for an empty list to be returned. If the list is empty, `get(0)` will fail with an exception as you have noticed.

Comment: Perhaps "Mumbai" is not a precise enough name.

Comment: I tested the code and mumbai did give me results.
Like I wrote in my answer, please try this line :
addressl = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 5);

Pass value more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the result you must check if its size is greater than zero or not.
And You have asked for only one result. You can try with this : addressl = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 5); 
This may yield result.